# vim for epd python on windows

Tags: python, windows, enthought, vim

I have installed [epd python distribution](http://www.enthought.com/products/epd.php) on my windows. Can anyone help me in setting up vim now? also, some help on basic quick tweaks on vim (syntax , color support etc.) would be helpful.

need quick help.

Comment: Maybe [here](http://blog.dispatched.ch/2009/05/24/vim-as-python-ide/) you'll find some inspiration.

Comment: What kind of problems do you have?! To get good answers, please ask precise questions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan of the [Solarized colorscheme](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized/vim-colors-solarized) and the [pymode plugin](https://github.com/klen/python-mode).  For installing Vim plugins in general, the [Vundle plug-in manager](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle) is great.